# Nested SQL Aggregate Function Query To Get Lowest Paid Employees Per Manager: My Query Is Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

The following is the prompt I'm trying to answer:

Show the manager number and the salary (only) of the lowest paid employee for that manager - labeled appropriately. Exclude salaries for employees whose manager is unknown. Exclude any groups here the minimum salary is less than $1000. List lowest salary first.

The following is my EMPLOYEES table:

```
create table EMPLOYEES
    (EmpID    char(4)         unique Not null,
     Ename    varchar(10),
     Job      varchar(9),
     MGR      char(4),
     Hiredate date,
     Salary   decimal(7,2),
     Comm     decimal(7,2),
     DeptNo   char(2)         not null,
         Primary key(EmpID),
         Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));


insert into EMPLOYEES values (7839,'King','President',null,'17-Nov-11',5000,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7698,'Blake','Manager',7839,'01-May-11',2850,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7782,'Clark','Manager',7839,'02-Jun-11',2450,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7566,'Jones','Manager',7839,'02-Apr-11',2975,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7499,'Allen','Salesman',7698,'20-Feb-11',1600,300,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7844,'Turner','Salesman',7698,'08-Sep-11',1500,0,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7900,'James','Clerk',7698,'22-Feb-12',950,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7521,'Ward','Salesman',7698,'22-Feb-12',1250,500,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7902,'Ford','Analyst',7566,'03-Dec-11',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7369,'Smith','Clerk',7902,'17-Dec-10',800,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7788,'Scott','Analyst',7566,'09-Dec-12',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7876,'Adams','Clerk',7788,'12-Jan-10',1100,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7934,'Miller','Clerk',7782,'23-Jan-12',1300,null,10);
```

The following is my query:

```
select empid, salary
from employees
where salary in
(select MIN(salary)
from employees
where empid in
(select empid
from EMPLOYEES
where JOB != 'manager'))
order by Salary asc;
```

The result is only the lowest paid person other than a manager. I need the lowest paid worker per manager, including the lowest paid manager under the president.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select empid, salary
from employees
where salary in
(select MIN(salary)
from employees
where empid in
(select empid
from EMPLOYEES
where JOB != 'manager'
 group by EmpID
 )
 and
 JOB != 'manager' and MGR is not null
 group by mgr
 )
order by Salary asc;
```

Comment: This is the format I was looking for.  How do I only list the salaries >= $1000

Comment: after Group by EmpID add having MIN(salary)>=1000

Comment: Thank you. My brain is fried, ive been writing SQL statement for hours and hours.  I am learning these nested aggregate functions on my own.  It is starting to frustrate me. May you please explain an easy way for me to know how to write the nested aggregates?

Comment: You can minimize your search criteria one by one! IF you make it as jumbo then you may find it difficult. What I did with your query is I first executed the "select empid from EMPLOYEES where JOB != 'manager'" this. Then I tried with second bracket which is select MIN(salary) from employees where empid in (select empid from EMPLOYEES where JOB != 'manager') and So on. and You have to have exposure to learn the SQL. You can keep practicing and you can improve your skills day by day! That's how I did! You can also go through some online tutorials too. Hope that helps you.

Comment: AAAAh!  You go with what you know first.  Then work your way out.  With easier nested queries I was just looking at the tables and going from the outside in. Thank you for your help!  Some answerers were leaving me bogus help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select MGR, MIN(salary)
from EMPLOYEES e
where Salary >= 1000 and MGR is not null
group by mgr
order by MIN(salary)
```

or perhaps:

```
select MGR, MIN(salary)
from EMPLOYEES e
where  MGR is not null
group by mgr
having min(salary) >= 1000
order by MIN(salary)
```

The statement "Exclude any groups here the minimum salary is less than $1000" is not clear to me.

Comment: I have to assume I don't know the salary